# Are there any reactions where two triatomics form three of the same diatomic?

Tags: molecules

A chemical equation: $\ce{A}+\ce{B}\to\ce{3C}$

Where $\ce{A}$ & $\ce{B}$ are triatomic molecules and C is a diatomic molecule. Find out $\ce{A}$, $\ce{B}$, $\ce{C}$?

So far the most worthy options for answer I've found are  $\ce{S_3}$ (trisulfur) and ozone ($\ce{O_3}$) as $\ce{A}$ & $\ce{B}$ and $\ce{SO}$ as $\ce{C}$. But I am not sure if this reaction will occur : $\ce{S3 + O3 \to 3SO}$

So, are there any better options? I am even worried about if this even has an answer in chemistry known to this day.

Comment: $\ce{N2O + NO2 -> 3NO}$. While still unrealistic, this one is more realistic than yours.

Comment: Is there any stipulation that A and B cannot be the same? Because $\ce{2 O3 -> 3 O2}$ feels like the most realistic thing here.

Comment: @Ivan does that reaction occur in reality?

Comment: @OrthocresolDoes that occur in reality?

Comment: The words "realistic" in orthocresol's comment and "unrealistic" in mine were there for a reason.